# Javascript translation

Tags: javascript, json, internationalization

I have to translate some word in my document.Some of them are local vars, others are coming from json.

Here an example:

```
var myFunction = function(data){

  data.forEach( function(entry){
    $('body').html('<div>Hello '+ entry.name_en +'</div>');
  });
  var city_en = "London";
  $('body').append('<p>'+city_en+'</p>');
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax('/api/map_entries', {
    dataType: 'json',
    success: dit.myFunction,
    error: function(xhr, st, et){
      console.warn(et);
    }
  })

});
```

So on my json i have something like:

```
{
 id: 1,
 name_en: 'mary',
 name_es: 'maria'
}
```

and as local variable i manually write them as:

```
var city_en: "London";
var city_es: "Barcelona";
```

My idea was to do it something like:

```
if( location.host + '/es' ){
 function get_i18n(en, es){
   // replace variable with es one.
 }
}
```

and then:

```
get_i18n(entry.name_en, entry.name_es);
```

But i'm not sure how to proceed and probably there is more elegant way to do it.
Any ideas?? :)